# Can I use Linq to DataSet to performe an insert/delete/update to a database?

Tags: c#, dataset, crud, linq-to-dataset

I'm not talking about Linq to SQL. Just Linq to DataSet.

Let's say I filled a dataset as explained here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314145/en-us

Now, how can I use Linq to performe inserts, updates and deletes on the dataset.

I did it as explained here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307587/en-us, but I want to do it with Linq. It's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to DataSet is used for querying dataset only.

[LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx)

> LINQ to DataSet makes it easier and faster to query over data cached
>   in a DataSet object. Specifically, LINQ to DataSet simplifies querying
>   by enabling developers to write queries from the programming language
>   itself, instead of by using a separate query language.

To perform Insert/Update/Delete operation on database, you may use [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx) or [entity framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/08/21/ado-net-entity-insert-update-and-delete.aspx).